# UWP Notifications from Background Service

Tags: c#, uwp, push-notification, electron

## Summary

I want to handle push notifications from a background-service (or an application shown as a tray icon) and show it as a native Notification in the Action Center (priority: Windows, but if it's cross platform, it works aswell).
The tray icon is optional and nice-to-have. The important thing is the application should run in the background and show notifications.

## Question

Can you suggest a way to show a native (windows) notification while the application is running in the background? Maybe an overview of the current (read: not deprecated) ways of achieving this?

## Details

There seem to be a thousand ways how to handle notifications in Windows and none seem to work flawlessly. UWP doesn't support tray icons (you have to do a hacky-thing with a WinForms application or WPF), Electron seems to work only when you have it as a shortcut to the Start Menu, WinForms is ugly to get to show notifications in the Action Center.

Can you suggest a way of doing this? Preferably without having to submit the application to the Store.

So far, it seems I will have to deploy a Notification Service on Azure, but I am not sure my application can handle these notifications while it is in the background.

JetBrains Toolbox provides a similar approach I want to accomplish: It is in the tray and can send notifications (like when I search for an update).

Comment: If you want to develop a UWP app, you could register a [Background Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks) and [send local toast notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast) from background task. Is this what you want?

Comment: I tried that... I probably could achieve something like that using Background Task and *Raw* notifications, but I don't know how reliable it can get.
And the other way I've found now is using the Notifications Hub hosted on Azure (50% of the documentation is legacy or outdated and the Nugets described are old aswell).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification

Again, I don't know how reliable this will work - because it's not documented.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure relevant things, but if you use Background Task, if you haven't exceeded the [Background task resource constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#background-task-resource-constraints) it always does work.

Comment: I tried running out of process background tasks but it stops when the app is closed

Comment: Azure is for notifications for the cloud. Do you need notifications from the cloud? Or are you talking about something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts